# puppet template with a part of the file editable

Tags: ruby, puppet

I have a config file that I deploys by puppet, it's a template. The program which is using this config file edit part of the file, which means that each puppet run replace the file.

Is it possible to declare a variable area not defined by puppet and which it can be edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this you should turn to [augeas](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/puppet_augeas). It will allow puppet to only change config keys it knows about or wants to control instead of the entire file. So you'd use the `file` resource to make sure the file exists, but not care about content. And then use `augeas` to manage the portion of content you wish to control.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, i already know augeas, but in my case it's a really complex xml file and I don't want to spend time for making a lense

Comment: You can also look at [puppet-concat](https://github.com/ripienaar/puppet-concat) module which allows you to construct a file from fragments.

Comment: I finally decided to create a custom script that compile all files in a folder. ( ".d" folder, like source.list.d for example). So I can add file via puppet or manually.